# How to show $σ^{r}(i) = i$? ( $σ^r$ denotes the power of a relation obtained from repeated composition)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

$N$<sub>≤n</sub> denotes the set of first n natural numbers i.e., $N$<sub>≤n</sub>$ = ${k | k ∈ N ∧ k ≤ n}$. $
An element $a ∈ A$ is called a fixed point of $f$ if $f(a) = a$ where $f: A → A$ is any function over an
arbitrary set A. Let σ: N<sub>≤n</sub> → N<sub>≤n</sub> denote an arbitrary permutation of the set N<sub>≤n</sub>.
Show that for all $ i ∈ $N<sub>≤n</sub>, there exists a smallest r ∈ N, where 1 ≤ r ≤ n, such that
σ<sup>r</sup>(i) = i.
Note that σ<sup>r</sup> denotes the power of a relation obtained from repeated composition.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it suffices to show that there is **some** positive integer $r$ such that $\sigma^r=\sigma$: if there is one at all, there is certainly a smallest one.

HINT: There are $n!$ permutations of $\Bbb N_{\le n}$. Consider the $n!+1$ permutations $\sigma^r$ for $r=1,\ldots,n!+1$, apply the pigeonhole principle, and prove and use the fact that $\sigma^{r+s}=\sigma^r\circ\sigma^s$ for any positive integers $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Could you break it down further? What do the n! Permutations mean here?

Comment: @RajeshShukla: The permutations of $\Bbb N_{\le n}$ are simply the bijections from $\Bbb N_{\le n}$ to itself.

Comment: Oh okay! Sorry but could you explain how the pigeon hole fits in here? I am unable to understand.

Comment: @RajeshShukla: You have $n!+1$ permutations $\sigma^r$ for $r=1,\ldots,n!+1$, but there are only $n!$ **different** permutations of $\Bbb N_{\le n}$, so ... ?