# Discrete Mathematics permutation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An element $a \in A$ is called a fixed point of $f$ if $f(a) = a$ where $f : A \to A$ is any function over an
arbitrary set $A$. Let $\sigma : \Bbb{N}_{\le n}\to \Bbb{N}_{\le n}$ denote an arbitrary permutation of the set $\Bbb{N}_{\le n}$.

(1) Show that for all $i \in\Bbb{N}_{\le n}$, there exists a smallest $r \in \Bbb N$, where $1\le r \le n$, such that $σ^r (i) = i$. Note that $σ^r$ denotes the power of a relation obtained from repeated composition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. This looks like a homework question. Please edit your question to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and please also tell us about your attempts to solve the question.

Comment: This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850771/how-to-show-%cf%83ri-i-%cf%83r-denotes-the-power-of-a-relation-obtained-fro); I’ve posted a hint there.